# How to open a web page inside a chrome packaged app?

Tags: google-chrome

Just like Android has a webview inside which a webpage can be opened, is it possible to do the same using chrome packaged app?

To give an example, how about opening a youtube link inside a chrome packaged app and then playing around with its DOM elements and adding more functionality to it using the app?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [webviews (like with Android)](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview) and then play with `executeScript` and `insertCSS`.

If you want a full example, I made a Chrome Packaged App for Google Play Music in 2013 (it could be deprecated) and the code is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/ArmandGrillet/App-for-Play-Music).